# PHP: 2 forms different action pages, only 1 form action works

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, action

I have two forms on my page. But the one action page(approve.php) doesn't seem to work. I need to set a field as active for the specific id, if it's approve or rejected. Is there any way to do it on one action page?

Or is there something I am doing wrong below? I blocked out the insert script because I didn't know if it was causing an issue. It was working before when I did the approval first...

Page:

```
<form method="get" action="approve.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="rows" value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>" />
            <p><a href='approve.php?id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>'><button url="#" class="btn btn-primary">Approve</button></a></p>
            </form>
            <form method="get" action="reject.php">
            <div id="reject-form-<?php echo $row[0] ?>" class="modal hide fade">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                            <h3><?php _e('Reject Reason'); ?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="message"></div>
                        <div class="controlgroup forgotcenter">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input id="reject" name="reject" type="text"/>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rw_id" value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>" />
                    <a href='reject.php?id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>'><button data-complete-text="<?php _e('Done'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="forgotsubmit"><?php _e('Submit'); ?></button></a>
                    <p class="pull-left"><?php _e('Please give a short reason for rejecting.'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#reject-form-<?php echo $row[0] ?>" id="rejectlink" tabindex=-1><button url="#" class="btn btn-primary">Reject</button></a></p>
            </form>
```

Reject:

```
$id = $_GET['rw_id'];
    $reason = $_GET['reject'];


    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'adjudication') or die('Connection error!');

    $update = "UPDATE login_fines_adjudicated SET reject_reason = '$reason' WHERE id ='$id'";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $update) or die('Database error!');

    $update1 = "UPDATE login_fines_adjudicated SET active = 1 WHERE id ='$id'";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $update1) or die('Database error, fine!');

    header('location:adjudication.php');
```

Approve:

```
$id = $_GET['rows'];

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'adjudication') or die('Connection error!');

    $updated = "UPDATE login_fines_adjudicated SET active = 1 WHERE id = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $updated) or die('Database error, active!');

    /**$insert = "INSERT INTO login_fines(`date`, `time_in`, `time_out`, `value`, `area`, `reason`, `licence`)"
    ." SELECT `date_issued`, `time_arrived`, `time_departed`, `value`, `location`, `violation_reason`, `licence`"
    ." FROM login_fines_adjudicated WHERE id = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $insert) or die('Database error, fines!');**/

    header('location:adjudication.php');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you shouldn't put form inside another form, instead you can use JS and submit the other form when first is submitted.

Comment: I will sanitize it, it's posting to the table. I just want to figure out why the approve.php is not setting the active field to 1...

Comment: you should have "submit" button in both form.

Comment: @Robert It's two separate forms...

Comment: @Hasina so <button type="submit"...></button>?

Comment: You're right I didn't notice it because of code formating. Why don't you use in first form `<input type="submit value="approve" />` ?

Comment: It's giving the same issue. I tried to approve the other rows from the database and it's submitting the query.. The first row of the database doesn't get submitted though. Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code like this :

```
<form method="get" action="approve.php?id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>">
    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Approve" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: It's giving the same issue. I tried to approve the other rows from the database and it's submitting the query.. The first row of the database doesn't get submitted though. Any thoughts??

Comment: Correct your approve.php with :
$id = $_GET['id']; 
and not :
$id = $_GET['rows']; :)

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? I can help if you post the error
Have you debug the value you get from the form? what do you get?

You can combine reject and approve in one script, and act different based on the value passed in. and I think post is better than get

```
<form method="post" action="approve.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="approve" value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>" />
  <p><a href='approve.php?id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>'><button url="#" class="btn btn-     primary">Approve</button></a></p>
</form>
```

---

```
<form method="post" action="reject.php">
 <div id="reject-form-<?php echo $row[0] ?>" class="modal hide fade"> 
 ....
<input type="hidden" name="reject" value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>" />
```

---

in action.php,

```
if(key_array_exists($_POST['approve'])) ...
if(key_array_exists($_POST['reject'])) ...
```