# 2 Formes in one page - second form is working without action

Tags: php, html, forms, post, action

My problem is close to this:
[PHP: 2 forms different action pages, only 1 form action works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895268/php-2-forms-different-action-pages-only-1-form-action-works)

I am making a php page that gets a search value of a student name from  form1 
and lists the matches students name with a button delete student under each one (form2)
Now form 2 action=delete.php is not working.

```
     <?php   $results = array();
        $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results);
        echo ''.$ln.' matches found as following:';

        for($i=0;$i<$ln;$i++){ ?> 

    <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="d" data-inset="false">
     <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">             
    <?php echo 'StudentName:'; echo (" $results[3] "); ?>
    </li>
     <li data-theme="c">

     <?php echo 'Email:'; echo (" $results[4] "); ?>

    </li></ul>

<?php    echo' <form name="form1" method="post" action="delete.php">  /*here is the problem*/

                            <input type="button" name="delete" class="button red" value="Delete member"> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="'. $results[0].'"    > 

    </form> '; ?>
```

You might ask why I print form with echo? because I tried this also and it did not work:

```
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="delete.php"> 

                    <input type="button" name="delete" class="button red" value="Delete member"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php  echo $results['0']; ?>" > 

                  </form>
```

and this is deletestudent.php

```
<?php

include ('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$mid=$_POST['id'];
             mysql_query(" DELETE FROM member WHERE (m_id='$mid') "); 
 }

  ?>
```

Hope the justification is clear, I am ready to write more details if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action attribute of a form is automatically performed only when a Submit button is pressed.

Try to change your code like this:

`<input type="submit" name="delete" class="button red" value="Delete member">`

The "Submit" button type will automatically trigger the action and should pass the form inputs as post parameters, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You are not submitting the form.

```
<input type="button" name="delete" class="button red" value="Delete member">
```

should be

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" class="button red" value="Delete member">
```

Comment: Could also be `<button type="submit"...>`